# stop scripting in a specified time(2 mins)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash

commonguess(){
 for guess in $(< passwordlist)
 do
  try=$(echo "$guess" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}' )
  if [ "$try" == "$xxx" ]
  then
   echo "$name:$try"
   return 0
  fi
done
return 1
}
dict(){...}
brute(){...}

while IFS=':' read -r name hashing;do
commonguess || dict || brute
done
```

my code has been fixed, and i need to do one more thing. when i run function brute, it should stop after 2 mins. I know sleep command can make the script pause, however i have been told it is not a good idea to use "kill". So i am wondering is there any way to do this.

Comment: `sleep 120 && kill $$ &`.If you are terminating the script anyway then using kill isn't a problem. If you are worried about cleaning up then use a trap as well.

Comment: If you are using `for variable in $(cat file)` your code has not been fixed. See this FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: `while [[ $(date +%s) -lt $deadline ]]; do`...?

Comment: @tripleee thanks for telling me that, i was showing my code to my teacher yesterday and i ask him about "cat file", he told just use $(cat file). I just checked it on shellcheck. Now i have fixed it!

Comment: Let's hope the lack of indentation isn't also perpetrated by your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

You'd get a better answer if you were more specific about what `brute` actually consists of.

If it's pure shell itself, the cleanest way to have it manage its execution time is to check the `SECONDS` variable frequently enough so you can abort the process by yourself it it ever goes over some threshold.

It it's external, you're not going to be able to avoid `kill`. Or some invoke wrapper that handles timeout on its own, that probably already exists.